# Convert seconds since epoch to joda DateTime in Scala

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime

I am attempting to take seconds since epoch and turn it into a DateTime object in Scala. I am use joda. Unfortunately whether I use seconds or milliseconds, I'm getting weird results. What am I doing wrong here?

```
scala> new org.joda.time.DateTime(1378607203*1000)
res2: org.joda.time.DateTime = 1969-12-31T02:31:40.984Z

scala> new org.joda.time.DateTime(1378607203)
res3: org.joda.time.DateTime = 1970-01-16T22:56:47.203Z
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Check a quick REPL session:

```
scala> 1378607203 * 1000
res6: Int = -77299016
```

Odd, isn't it? :) Can you guess why this is happening?

I will give you a hint extracted from `DateTime`'s constructor you are trying to use.

```
DateTime(long instant)
```

Still don't get it? Let's try a slightly different version:

```
scala> 1378607203L * 1000
res8: Long = 1378607203000
```

Notice the `L` indicating a literal of type Long. You are asking for 1 trillion! And Int only go as far as 2 billons:

```
scala> Int.MaxValue
res7: Int = 2147483647
```

So doing `DateTime(1378607203L*1000)` will make it work.

Comment: how do I convert joda dateTime (`1970-01-16T22:56:47.203Z`) to Unix time?

Comment: I'd say first studying the date and time apis. secondly asking a question is SO. In its own question, no in somebody else's question.