# How to convert unix timestamp to date in Spark

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, timestamp, nscala-time

I have a data frame with a column of unix timestamp(eg.1435655706000), and I want to convert it to data with format 'yyyy-MM-DD', I've tried nscala-time but it doesn't work.

```
val time_col = sqlc.sql("select ts from mr").map(_(0).toString.toDateTime)
time_col.collect().foreach(println)
```

and I got error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1435655706000" is malformed at "6000"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680398/convert-seconds-since-epoch-to-joda-datetime-in-scala

Comment: Solved, import org.joda.time._, sqlc.sql("select ts from mr").map(line => new DateTime(line(0)).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

Answer (score 37):

Here it is using Scala DataFrame functions: [from_unixtime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#from_unixtime-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) and [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_date-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-)

```
// NOTE: divide by 1000 required if milliseconds
// e.g. 1446846655609 -> 2015-11-06 21:50:55 -> 2015-11-06 
mr.select(to_date(from_unixtime($"ts" / 1000)))
```

Comment: Since I want to have it in UTC I did the following: to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime($"buyOrdrEntryTime"/1000,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),"Europe/Berlin").as("buyOrdrEntryTime")

Answer (score 29):

Since spark1.5 , there is a builtin UDF for doing that.

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("select from_unixtime(ts,'YYYY-MM-dd') as `ts` from mr")
```

Please check [Spark 1.5.2 API Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) for more info.

Comment: You can also import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ to use these functions in function calls. Example: df.select(from_unixtime($"ts_col"/1000,"yyyy-MM-dd")).toDF("event_date").groupBy("event_date").count

Comment: The problem is current time zone will be used for conversion, not UTC

Comment: Hi @Oleg , I solved the UTC problem in this way: to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime($"buyOrdrEntryTime"/1000,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),"Europe/Berlin").as("buyOrdrEntryTime"). It is important to specify the Time Zone in this way in order to avoid day light savings problems. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Playing With BI is not UTC if the timestamp were not generated in Berlin's timezone.
If your data is in UTC and you want to be sure it is considered as UTC, you can specify Europe/London.

Answer (score 18):

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
```

You need to import the following libraries.

```
val stri = new DateTime(timeInMillisec).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Or adjusting to your case :

```
 val time_col = sqlContext.sql("select ts from mr")
                     .map(line => new DateTime(line(0).toInt).toString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

There could be another way :

```
  import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
  
  val date = (new DateTime() + ((threshold.toDouble)/1000).toInt.seconds )
             .toString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 7):

You needn't convert to String before applying toDataTime with nscala_time

`import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._`

```
scala> 1435655706000L.toDateTime
res4: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-06-30T09:15:06.000Z
```

`

Comment: Or just `import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.richLong` if you're not a fan of hidden implicits

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this issue using the [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library by mapping on the `DataFrame` and converting the `DateTime` into a String :

```
import org.joda.time._
val time_col = sqlContext.sql("select ts from mr")
                         .map(line => new DateTime(line(0)).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following syntax in Java

```
input.select("timestamp)
            .withColumn("date", date_format(col("timestamp").$div(1000).cast(DataTypes.TimestampType), "yyyyMMdd").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType))
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is:

```
input.withColumn("time", concat(from_unixtime(input.col("COL_WITH_UNIX_TIME")/1000,
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), typedLit("."), substring(input.col("COL_WITH_UNIX_TIME"), 11, 3), 
typedLit("Z")))
```

where time is a new column name and COL_WITH_UNIX_TIME is the name of the column which you want to convert. This will give data in millis, making your data more accurate, like: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`