# How to convert string to epoch time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one column its has epoch time( String type) in the table.Want to minus one hour from epoch time .I'm trying to convert a string into epoch time and do the minus. But I am unable to convert the string to epoch time. Any help, please?

for Eg:

```
val epochTime="1499013460"
```

I want ti subtract one hour from the above epoch time.

Thanks!

Comment: post an example of your String date format if possible

Comment: Have you tried looking here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134969/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-in-spark

Comment: yes i tried .Hitting with Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1499015689" is malformed at "9".                                   val table=Seq(("1499015689",1),("1499015689",2)).toDF("col1","col2")
       
     val time_col = table.select(col("col1"))
                         .map(line => new DateTime(line(0)).toString("yyyy-MM-dd")).toDF()                                                                                                                         Please let me know did i made any mistake.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an epoch time values and all you want to do is to subtract an hour from it you can go with the simplest solution possible which is:

```
val secondsPerHour = 60 * 60
val withHourSubtracted = (epochTime.toLong - secondsPerHour).toString
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach:

```
scala> import java.time.Instant
import java.time.Instant

scala> val myString = Instant.now().toString
myString: String = 2017-07-02T17:04:39.911Z

scala> Instant.parse(myString).getEpochSecond
res8: Long = 1499015079
```