# Extract date from unix_timestamp which is in string format Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table with timestamp in string format "1504856248587", I want to convert it into dateformat "2017-09-08". How can i do in using spark-scala API ?

Comment: cast it to `bigint` and then use `from_unixtime`.

Comment: You can use either from_unixtime or Jodatime. Please refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134969/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-in-spark)