# Convert from timestamp to specific date in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, type-conversion, timestamp, converters

I would like to convert on a specific column the timestamp in a specific date.

Here is my input :

```python
+----------+
| timestamp|
+----------+
|1532383202|
+----------+
```

What I would expect :

```python
+------------------+
|      date        |
+------------------+
|24/7/2018 1:00:00 |
+------------------+
```

If possible, I would like to put minutes and seconds to 0 even if it's not 0.

For example, if I have this :

```python
+------------------+
|      date        |
+------------------+
|24/7/2018 1:06:32 |
+------------------+
```

I would like this :

```python
+------------------+
|      date        |
+------------------+
|24/7/2018 1:00:00 |
+------------------+
```

What I tried is :

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

table = table.withColumn(
    'timestamp',
    unix_timestamp(date_format('timestamp', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS'))
)
```

But I have NULL.

Comment: In almost all cases, you should [avoid using a `udf` when there is an equivalent API function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance). Depending on the size of your data, it may not make a noticeable difference but it's *much* more efficient to allow all of the processing happen inside the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use the datetime library to convert timestamps to your wanted format. You should also use user-defined functions to work with spark DF columns. Here's what I would do:

```python
# Import the libraries
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from datetime import datetime

# Create a function that returns the desired string from a timestamp 
def format_timestamp(ts):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')

# Create the UDF
format_timestamp_udf = udf(lambda x: format_timestamp(x))

# Finally, apply the function to each element of the 'timestamp' column
table = table.withColumn('timestamp', format_timestamp_udf(table['timestamp']))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good edit there. +1 for showing that you can directly convert to `:00:00` without having to use regex. I've added it to my answer as well. Your answer works but it's preferable to [avoid using `udf` when possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance).

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

Inspired by @Tony Pellerin's answer, I realize you can go directly to the `:00:00` without having to use `regexp_replace()`:

```python
table = table.withColumn("date", f.from_unixtime("timestamp", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:00:00"))
table.show()
#+----------+-------------------+
#| timestamp|               date|
#+----------+-------------------+
#|1532383202|23/07/2018 18:00:00|
#+----------+-------------------+
```

---

Your code doesn't work because [`pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp) will:

> Convert time string with given pattern (‘yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss’, by default) to Unix time stamp (in seconds), using the default timezone and the default locale, return null if fail.

You actually want to do the inverse of this operation, which is [convert from an integer timestamp to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134969/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-in-spark). For this you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

table = table.withColumn("date", f.from_unixtime("timestamp", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS"))
table.show()
#+----------+-------------------+
#| timestamp|               date|
#+----------+-------------------+
#|1532383202|23/07/2018 18:07:00|
#+----------+-------------------+
```

Now the `date` column is a string:

```python
table.printSchema()
#root
# |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
# |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

So you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace()` to make the minutes and seconds zero:

```python
table.withColumn("date", f.regexp_replace("date", ":\d{2}:\d{2}", ":00:00")).show()
#+----------+-------------------+
#| timestamp|               date|
#+----------+-------------------+
#|1532383202|23/07/2018 18:00:00|
#+----------+-------------------+
```

The regex pattern `":\d{2}"` means match a literal `:` followed by exactly 2 digits.