# Date formatting in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

Just want to ask if is there a way to convert this type of date

**MM/DD/YYYY (currently on string. Example: "FEBRUARY/20/2020")
to
2020-02-20 format as date?**

I've tried to use to_date and SimpleDateFormat functions but still doesn't work.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: check here https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Expression-UnixTimestamp.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134969/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-in-spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala does not have its own Date formatting functions. All of it is inherited from Java. So you will have to use `SimpleDateFormat` or any other available Java alternatives. That will completely work with Scala

Comment: Correct, except that `SimpleDateFormat` was supplanted years ago by the modern `DateTimeFormatter` class.