# convert epoch to datetime in Scala / Spark

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, jodatime

I'm converting String representing a DateTime to unix_time (epoch) using :

```
def strToTime(x: String):Long = { DateTimeFormat.
    forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime(x).getMillis()/1000 }
```

to get a list of Long like this :

```
.map( p=> List( strToTime(p(0) ) ) )
```

my question is - what is the easiest way to turn in backwards?
something like:

```
def timeToStr(x: Long):String = { x*1000L.toDateTime}
```

that I could use on the above List(Long)

I have read  [Convert seconds since epoch to joda DateTime in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680398/convert-seconds-since-epoch-to-joda-datetime-in-scala) but can't apply it successfully

Comment: You just need to put braces around x*1000L. i.e(x*1000L).toDateTime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a precedence problem - `.toDateTime` is being applied to `1000L` before `*` is applied. Bracket the operations to make the call order clear:

```
def timeToStr(x: Long): String = { (x*1000L).toDateTime }
```

Comment: not working for me:
Am I missing a library or something? I have imported: 
import org.joda.time.format._
import org.joda.time._
but still get    

scala> def timeToStr(x: Long):String = { (x*1000L).toDateTime}    

<console>:31: error: value toDateTime is not a member of Long

Comment: @ZahiroMor Ah, I presumed you had set up a suitable "toDateTime" "pimp my library" extension (using, for example, an implicit conversion) - something like: `implicit class ToDateTime(millis: Long) { def toDateTime = DateTime(millis) }`.

Answer (score 12):

Follows my approach!

```
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def epochToDate(epochMillis: Long): String = {
    val df:SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    df.format(epochMillis)
}
```

Follows a test run.

```
scala> epochToDate(1515027919000L)
res0: String = 2018-01-03
```

Comment: Upvote as a simple solution that doesn't need the Joda library. However, I think one step is missing and it is converting the epoch value to Date. Otherwise, the formatter just sees it as an object.

Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1515027919L))

Answer (score 6):

The opposite of `parseDateTime` is `print` :)

```
def timeToStr(epochMillis: Long): String =
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").print(epochMillis)
```

Comment: I think you mean   `def timeToStr(epochMillis: Long):String =`

Comment: you're actually getting `291` for days? That looks like you may have  a typo in your formatter string. In particular, it looks like you're using `"YYYY-MM-dd1 HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: actually it was DD for days and not dd. my bad.